# ending conversation scoped bean and then redirect when command button clicked

Tags: java, redirect, jsf-2, glassfish-3, cdi

I have a simple command button

```
<h:commandButton value="Create Form Event" action="#{formEventController.createFormEvent}"/>
```

which calls the following simple action listener

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class FormEventController implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    ...

    public String createFormEvent()
    {
        conversation.end();
        return "events?id=" + form.getId() + "&faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

so basically I want a button that when clicked will end a conversation, and then redirect to a new page...

this works ONCE, then every time after I see the following in my logs..  (from the users point of view, everything worked properly.. when the button is clicked, the redirect works properly)

> SEVERE:
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>           at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)
>           at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:834)
>           at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:832)
>           at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.deactivate(AbstractConversationContext.java:250)
>           at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.deactivateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:131)
>           at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.afterPhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:96)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:189)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:107)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1534)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at net.balusc.http.multipart.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:78)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:326)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>
> SEVERE: WebModule[]PWC1322: Error
>   invoking requestDestroyed method on
>   ServletRequestListener
>   org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Context is not active
>           at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.deactivate(AbstractConversationContext.java:263)
>           at org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldListener.requestDestroyed(WeldListener.java:125)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.fireRequestDestroyedEvent(StandardContext.java:4588)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:243)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:328)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:227)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:170)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue has been resolved in latest version of weld, see related bug report

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-833

Comment: how stupid can somebody be to make such mistake in Weld ? and affect so many people.